# Autoscaleable solution for SQL server in the cloud

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, cloud

I have a project running on AWS using EC2 for web servers and a SQL server. The usage of the project goes through seasonal changes. There is a very limited time (typically few days a year) where there is  high activity (hundreds of requests per second). The rest of the time there is very low activity.

I'm looking for a SQL compatible cloud product that will autoscale as needed. I'm hoping to need minimal changes to my code to adapt to this solution. I know I can use different kinds of auto-scaling services with more extensive code changes.

Comment: Is the DB constantly changing or are the hundreds of requests per second all (or nearly all) reads?

Comment: @TTT read/write mix

Comment: Too bad. I was thinking along the same lines as Tim's read replicas idea.

Answer (score 4):

Amazon RDS is not elastic in this way - it's one of the least elastic Amazon services. You can get a larger instance size while it's running, but this can take some time (minutes to hours). If you plan to do that you're best off with a multi-AZ setup, as that way the new instance is created from the backup database not the master. With single AZ master can pause for a minute. Azure is much the same.

Unfortunately I don't think the solution you want exists in AWS. You'll have to scale up your database manually before these peaks or you can scale out using read replicas. Read replicas typically require application changes.

You could choose to re-architect in a way that takes this into account, using NoSQL, Redis/Memcached, or some other technology that's built to scale.

Comment: Is there a better solution on Google or Azure?

Comment: Azure, I don't think so. Google, I have no idea. SQL databases are one of the more difficult things to scale.

Comment: I disagree, Azure has Elastic pools: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-pool/ @RonHarlev

Comment: @SeanGallardy good solution, I didn't know about that one.